# invalid argument supplied for foreach() 2

Tags: php, laravel

I tried a few times but it's still wrong, just trying to list all the classes in my display file like this:

```
@foreach ($kelas as $k)
   <option value="{{$k->id}}">{{$k->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

But getting an error which says"Undefined variable: kelas"

In my controller, I have the following function:

```
$kelas=Kelas::all();
    return view('student.edit',['student'=>$student],['kelas'=>$kelas]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array syntax error with your code, change it to this:

```php
  return view('student.edit',['student'=>$student, 'kelas'=>$kelas]);
```